# Why don't stepper motors ring indefinitely?

Tags: electromagnetism, stepper-motor, electromagnetic, stepper-driver

I don't have much of a EM background but I have used stepper motors for things. What's not clear to me is why don't stepper motors ring indefinitely?

Excluding physical friction, what actually causes a stepper motor to stop at a given location? It's clear how the acceleration takes place to the next position - there is an induced magnetic field which forces the motor turn.

But once that acceleration has taken place and the shaft reaches the next step location, significant momentum has been built up and the shaft is traveling at a certain rotational velocity. This will result in the motor over shooting the step location - while it's clear the magnetic field will attempt to accelerate the shaft in the other direction once over-shoot occurs, it seems energy is simply being added to the system producing a harmonic oscillator whose magnitude will continue to increase instead of decrease.

Could someone explain what mechanism is causing energy to leave the system?

If it was frictionless, would oscillation be indefinite?

Comment: I am confused. I thought all ringing dies down sooner or later, if there is no force to accelerate to a new position.

Comment: Even if friction was absent, you will still have *some* energy losses from induced eddy currents if the rotor doesn't stop.

Comment: The pulse width only moves the rotor about 75%, then the next magnet pole pulls the rotor into place and holds it tight. These magnets are very powerful. You need another pulse to move the rotor another step.

Comment: Don't neglect friction, that will withdraw energy from the system. Other things will as well, eddy currents, air viscosity, sound emission. You'd have to work very hard to make a non-dissipative system.

Comment: Consider that when the rotor is turning (oscillating), there is a back-EMF that appears in the stator winding.  This back-EMF produces a change in the stator current which opposes the motion, slightly.  The factor that controls the amount of damping is the resistance seen by the back-EMF looking out of the motor.  If you are using current regulators, the resistance seen will be quite high...and, the damping quite low.  Understood?